# Error installing passenger on OSX: Curl development headers with SSL support not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, libcurl, passenger

I am getting "Curl development headers with SSL support" error when trying to install passenger nginx module on OSX machine.

I downloaded curl-7.19.7 from Apple and it installed fine.

What's going on??

Comment: Facing the same issue on 10.8 mountain lion server and breaking my head for hours

Answer (score 0):

The default Apple installation includes the binaries, but not the development headers. When you build the package from source (even from Apple's open source packages) it includes the headers, so you can build the native extensions. Therefore, when you manually install Apple's nginx packages, you get everything you need to build the extension. Kinda like what happens when you try to install the mysql gem on OS X Server if you haven't installed Apple's MySQL source packages. b0rked until you build from Apple's (modified) source.

Comment: I built the package from source, shouldn't it include the headers?

Comment: Hmm... I think perhaps I misread your question. What version of OS X are you running? Also, which Passenger version? There's a similar issue in Ubuntu 10.04: http://code.google.com/p/phusion-passenger/issues/detail?id=533

Comment: It might be an issue with the Curl implementation in your OS X version... are you running Snow LEopard?

Comment: Yup running snow leopard. Tried latest passenger version (inc. beta). I noticed there is a similar issue with Ubuntu...